# How to cut off string in preactjs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cut off string in PreactJS as follow,

```
mystring.subString(0, 10)
```

unfortunately, error found that '**subString**' undefined or something else seem it does not work. Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: `subString` -> `substring`.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Preact`, it's a syntax error

It should be : `'mystring'.substring(0, 10)`

Comment: @ppshein Can you show more code? It seems that your `mystring` variable is undefined.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to check undefine for `mystring`

Answer (score 0):

@daniel is correct. And the following is also possible :-

`'mystring'.substr(0, 10)`

Comment: Using substr is _possible_ but **strongly discouraged**. See the [doc of the function on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [a related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640271/why-string-prototype-substr-seems-to-be-deprecated).