# How to get ymd by substring with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

With this code to get ymd:

```js
var ymd = '20190716';
var year = ymd.substring(0, 4);
var month = ymd.substring(4, 2);
var day = ymd.substring(6, 2);

console.log(year);
console.log(month);
console.log(day);
```

I think its the right way to get substring from index to length. So ...

Want:

```
2019
07
16
```

But got:

```
2019
19
1907
```

Why?

Comment: If "start" is greater than "end", it will swap the two arguments:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

> The substring() method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

and

> If indexStart is greater than indexEnd, then the effect of substring() is as if the two arguments were swapped.

So when you pass `4, 2` or `6, 2`, you're saying that you want the end index to come *before* the start index, so the arguments get switched, and you get index 2 to 4, and index 2 to 6.

Perhaps you wanted `substr`, which does what you're expecting:

> The arguments of substring() represent the starting and ending indexes, while the arguments of substr() represent the starting index and the number of characters to include in the returned string.

```js
var ymd = '20190716';
var year = ymd.substr(0, 4);
var month = ymd.substr(4, 2);
var day = ymd.substr(6, 2);
console.log(year);
console.log(month);
console.log(day);
```

But it's (kinda) deprecated. I'd prefer `substring` or `slice`, and pass indicies.

> The substring() method swaps its two arguments if indexStart is greater than indexEnd, meaning that a string is still returned. The slice() method returns an empty string if this is the case.

`slice`'s behavior is a bit more intuitive IMO.

Comment: Interesting: [Why String.prototype.substr() seems to be deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52640271/1220550)

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of `substring()` is not the length of the substring you would like to get but the end index.

So `substring(4,2)` starts at index 4 and ends at 2. Giving you "19"

Comment: `.substr()`, on the other hand, accepts the start index and the length.

Comment: @AKX [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated. [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is a better option

Comment: Interesting: [Why String.prototype.substr() seems to be deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52640271/1220550)

Comment: @adiga although .slice() also has the end index as second argument

Comment: @BasSlagter yeah. You'd have to do `str.slice(index, index + length)`. I like it because I don't have to google to check every time if it's `substring` or `subString` or `substr`. It behaves exactly like `Array.prototype.slice`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JavaScript regex:

```js
const date = "20190716";
const pattern = /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/;
[result, year, month, day] = date.match(pattern);

console.log(year, month, day);
```

**1st Capturing Group (\d{4})**

- `\d{4}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `{4}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times

**2nd Capturing Group (\d{2})**

- `\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

**3rd Capturing Group (\d{2})**

- `\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times