# Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i had a code in javascript and I'm trying to convert it to typescript

```js
          var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
          if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
            ip = ip.substr(7);
```

this is a piece of my code which used to work correctly in js but now I get this error for substr

`Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'. Property 'substr' does not exist on type 'string[]'.ts(2339)`

I assume I should add type for `ip` variable but I don't know what type should exactly be assigned to it.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add `String` type

Comment: Just as a note on using `substr` [and why it should probably be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640271/why-string-prototype-substr-seems-to-be-deprecated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a reason why the property is defined as `string | string[]` (and this is why you use TypeScript in the first place). Probably, there are several values for a header key, so simply “assuming” it to be **always** a `string` is **wrong**!

Simplest solution -- do a type check before you try to invoke `.substr` as follows:

```
if (typeof ip === 'string' && ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
  // …
```

Better would be, to also handle the case that it actually is an array. But the logic depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: this is the answer I've been looking for, completely solved my issue.
thanks @qqilihq

Answer (score -2):

Use `String` instead of `string` refer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-typescript/)

So, your code will be

```
          var ip: String = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
          if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
            ip = ip.substr(7);
```

Comment: I did what you said,
problem with substr looks to be fixed but now I get this error on ip 
`Type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'String'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'String'.ts(2322)`